# Excel-Finding if cell values match and entering corresponding data for matching cells?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to see 1) if a cell value in excel matches another cell in a table and 2) For the matching cells, enter corresponding information from the table . I came up with the following formula, but it doesn't work: IF(OR(EXACT(A2,$O$2:$O$467)),VLOOKUP(O2,O2:S2,4),"")

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Adding "FALSE" as the 4th parameter in the VLOOKUP function will return data only for an exact match.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(O2,O2:S2,4,FALSE),"")
```

(Note: IFERROR only works in Excel 2007 and later.  If you are using an earlier version you can use `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(O2,O2:S2,4,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(O2,O2:S2,4,FALSE))`.)

This will not work if you are looking for a case-sensitive match.

Comment: Here's some information about performing case-sensitive lookups: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214264

Comment: FYI Microsoft's solution is really weak.  It can't find "Joe" in a table if it is preceded by "joe".